# Rock paper Scissors bot algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, theory

In my school our teacher is holding a Rock, paper, scissors bot competition. I know how to program in Python, but I have no idea how to program a bot that would have a bigger chance of success than one that randomly selects its weapons. I think it is possible to store all previous moves and then look for patterns in order to defy attacks. Am I going in a right direction? Any ideas?

Comment: Do bots play other bots?  Any patterns that exist with human play would be psychological; I think a computer would just play randomly.

Comment: There are a couple of relevant links in the "related" sidebar, and over on CodeGolf.SE we *don't* have Rho Sham Bo (though it is a good idea), but do have [a question on the Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2357) where you can see some approaches to *simple* AI coding for a competitive game.

Comment: If your opponent is (truely) randomly choosing moves then there is no strategy that will win more often than also randomly choosing.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I think that depends on how will they be programmed, and you can't know that a priori

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yes, bots battle other bots.

Comment: Typically random play is a fall back position for when you're being beaten, as it does offer a floor.

Comment: @JanL - This seems worth reading: http://dan.egnor.name/iocaine.html

Comment: @Peter that is not quite correct.  for example, the 'strategy' of always choosing rock would win just as often.  as would, in fact, any strategy you can dream up.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Your comment is really usefull, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is proven for rock-paper-scissors that a **random bot will be at the median of each rank**.

Therefore, I'd **create a set of bots**, each calculating one heuristic and running on the background on parallel. For each turn, each bot will virtually "draw" and check if he had won or lost - if it would have played this turn. Each bot will keep track on how many games it would have won if it played, and how many it would have lost.

One of these bots will be the random attacker.

Each time it is your turn: **choose which bot won so far the most** [greedy] - and use it.

Using this approach you are **guaranteed  to be at the top median** of your class! [with enough rounds of games of course]

Comment: can you provide any link or source?

Comment: @RikP.: Can you be more specific, source to what? This algorithm? The fact that a random bot will be at the median? [I don't remember where I read it - but it is easy to prove].

Comment: Sorry, I ment about the statistical statement. Would you care to explain (in short terms obviously) how would you prove it?

Comment: @RikP.: Assume each game concists of rounds. A random bot is obviously winning,losing and drawing 1/3 of the rounds of eah game [1/3 of each]. Thus, it will win win half of the games it participates. Since this is a zero-sum game [one winner, one loser]: The total score of the random bot at infinity will sum up to 0, which is the median of the scores [again, because it is zero sum game]. There are more mathematical details to be done, but it is the main idea behind the proof.

Comment: That won't necessarily work, because your opponent is probably choosing its moves based on the history of your playing bot. So your bot makes its moves based on its opponent's history, but your opponent makes its moves based on your own history. Both sides can be trying to double-guess the opponent's next move. So you can't necessarily substitute in a different bot that "won" in the background, and be guaranteed success.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen: No approach guarantees success. This approach is greedy solution, aiming to do better then random bot - but never worse then it. And I believe it does it. This approach can actually tell you - you won't be the worst player! And the beauty of it: It can be combined with any other heuristics: just add each new heuristic as another background bot!

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing against humans, you are on the right track. Storing previous moves is key. Here are two articles that will prove helpful to you. [How to win at rock, paper, scissors](http://andrewgelman.com/2007/05/how_to_win_at_r/). And wikipedia's entry on [strategy and algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors#Strategies).

Comment: +1 for good links. The wiki link even has some concrete algorithm suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

[Rock Paper Scissors Programming Competition site](http://www.rpscontest.com/leaderboard) contains a large number of competing programs (they are even written in python).

If this is your school assignment, it may be considered cheating, because all submitted sources are publicly available. But, then again, they are available to other students too.

Answer (score 0):

Where might be some potential profit in trying to figure out the strategies of the other bots, for instance, if it's a forced participation, there will be some lazy student who makes up a bot that would always throw up scissors.

I propose another strategy (I've heard about it on some similar competition, but can't track the source anymore), suppose that you could let several bots running (if not, cooperate with some of your classmates to run this strategy).

Let's say you have 4 bots A,B,C,D

Imagine each bot play 100 times against the others. Let your B,C,D bots play for the first let's say 10 times play a strategy that would let recognise it as a bot from your team, say 'RPPSPPSSRS', let your A bot play some other strategy that would let it be recognized by the bots B,C,D.

Then, in the next 90 round let the bots B,C,D lose ('paper') to the A and play random against the others. Let the bot A win ('scissors') from the B,C,D and play random against the others.

Thus, the bot A gets a huge advantage.

Comment: @JanL: what exactly is not an option?

Comment: JanL, I think you're misunderstanding. Max is recommending you have one bot, with four "sub-bots." The switching between the "sub-bots" would be programmed in to your bot's code.

Comment: I believe my interpretation is correct. If I'm wrong, please explain

Comment: @JanL: Could you explain why in your opinion this strategy is not an option? For which reason?

Comment: I can't have more bots and my classmates aren't allowed to help in any way.